# Chinese Year on a Postmark

Tags: translation

Another postmark question: I don't know which year it is (perhaps 1918, 1928?).

[image: Kikungshan]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It's most probably written vertically, right to left:

七年八月十一 Year 7, Month 8, 11(th day). 1938/8/11 (Year 1 is 1932).

No idea what the 九/9 at the end stands for.

EDIT

As Wang Dingwei says, Henan wasn't part of Manchukuo. So year 7 is probably 1918. [紀元轉換](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%91%E5%9C%8B%E7%B4%80%E5%B9%B4)

Comment: Usually it's the serial number of the rubber stamp but I could be wrong.

Comment: 七年 as in 民国七年， should be 1918

Comment: 九 means time, 9 AM. Here is a [comprehensive source](http://www.p1878.com/bbs/viewthread.php?tid=46657&extra=page%3D2&page=1).

Answer (score -1):

Guessing here: 18th January 1941, that is Manchuguo year 9 in Jigongshan, occupied Henan.

Comment: Manchukuo started at 1934.

Comment: Also Manchukuo never occupied Henan.